# При переходе с одной jsp страницы на другую получаю ошибку 404

Tags: java, spring-mvc

делаю туториал Spring MVC + Hibernate CRUD  и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Первую страницу index.jsp он видит и спокойно ее отображает, но при переходе на страницу /employees выдает ошибку 404

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Файл настройки Spring где ему искать jsp
[image]mgur.com/nFHJ6.jpg

Контроллер
[image: Настройка в spring где искать страницы]

Структура проекта.(Файл index.jsp вынесен в корень папки web потому что в папке views он ее просто не видит. Перенос страницы employeeList  в корень папки web проблемы не решает он ее также не видит)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

web.xml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и сам index.jsp
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте сюда ещё серверный лог.